# Class file not found while instantiating a class

Tags: php

Though there is not any error while requiring the file. I have not found error while instantiating the class.

```
//$this->currentController = /var/www/html/RoomFinder/App/Controllers/Home.php
require $this->currentController;
//No any errors till here and note that file_exists returns true
$this->currentController = new $this->currentController;
```

Here is the error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '/var/www/html/RoomFinder/App/Controllers/Home.php' not found in /var/www/html/RoomFinder/Core/Router.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/RoomFinder/public/index.php(10): Router->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/RoomFinder/Core/Router.php on line 29
```

Comment: @praveen idk why you marked it as duplicate though it is clearly not an syntax error.

Comment: Hi Yojan, I believe that's covered in one of the answers. Let me know if it's not covered, I am happy to reopen. `:)`

Comment: @praveen There is not an error after require. The error comes after instantiating the class. So is there an syntax error in that line? P.S. it's not covered in the link you provided.

Comment: Crazy one... Okay, haven't seen this issue yet. Reopened. All the best finding the solution... Let me know too! `:)`

Comment: What is the actual class name in that file? You need to use `new` with a class name not a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate a path, rather than an object.

```
 require $this->currentController; // is including a path to a php file.
```

Assuming your class within that path is called 'Home' 
try this:

```
 require $this->currentController;
 $this->currentController = new Home;
```

although, i'd suggest refactoring this code to be easier to understand:

```
 $controllerpath = $this->currentController;
 $controllername = 'Home';
 require $controllerpath;
 $this->currentController = new $controllername;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you point out to some resources to learn best practices to write better code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require $this->currentController;
$this->currentController = new Home;
```

I think is better if you instantiate Home class in another var like this:

```
$home = new Home;
```